# May I connect directly to GPIO headers without stripboard

Tags: gpio, sensor

I wish to install a thermo and a humidity sensor on my Raspi but I have no place for a stripboard or veroboard in my waterproofcase. So I would like to know whether I can connect them directly on the GPIO headers... everything with the resistors.
Thank you for help
majsperry

Comment: Be very careful not to bridge GPIO pins that you don't want to bridge ;-)

Comment: I'm curious, can you post some information about the weatherproof case you are planning to use in your project along with any details about how you plan to power your Pi remotely?

Comment: To HeatfanJohn The weatherproof case I am using is PICE from http://ed-venture.biz/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Stripboards, breadboards, breakouts, etc. are just conveniences.   You can just attach whatever directly to the specific GPIO pins you want to use.